# GCP List Folders Via API - "methodResource() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given"

Tags: python, api, google-cloud-platform

Using the API from their documentation page works: https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v2beta1/folders/list?apix_params=%7B%22parent%22%3A%22organizations%2F319808429458%22%7D

However, when using the API within Python, I'm presently receiving the error:

"methodResource() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given"

My code is as follows:

```
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(JSONPath)
cloudresman = discovery.build('cloudresourcemanager', 'v2beta1', credentials=credentials)
ORGID = "organizations/12345678910"
folderdicts = cloudresman.folders(ORGID).list().execute()
```

From what I've read online, this seems to be a problem with the class; but of course, Google have made the 'discovery' class. Am I doing something wrong? Can anyone else use the Python API to list folders within their GCP organisation?

Answer (score 1):

In my code, I have this working example for a search.

```
...
    CREDENTIALS = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
    SERVICE_RESOURCE_MANAGER_FOLDER = discovery.build('cloudresourcemanager', 'v2', credentials=CREDENTIALS)
    request = SERVICE_RESOURCE_MANAGER_FOLDER.folders().search(body=body)
    response = request.execute()
    return response
```

In your beta API, I guess that the problem is the ORGID set on the `folders()` method. Did you try to set it in the `list()` as the body param name in my code?

Comment: Hmm, this is weird... when using cloudresman = discovery.build('cloudresourcemanager', 'v2', credentials=credentials) and try cloudresman.folders().search, I get the response: 'function' object has no attribute 'search'

The same thing happens with the 'list' attribute.

Comment: What about your requirement file? Can you share it?